# Correct way to set static enum vars in cpp file

Tags: c++, static-members

Getting follwoing error while setting static var

```
error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

**"GameScene.h"**

```
#ifndef __GAME_SCENE_H__
#define __GAME_SCENE_H__

class Game {
public:

    enum InteractionMode {
        EDITING,
        PLAYING };
    static Game::InteractionMode mode;
}
#endif // __GAME_SCENE_H__
```

**"GameScene.cpp"**

```
#include "GameScene.h"

Game *Game::singleton() {
    if (_GameSingleton == NULL) {
        _GameSingleton = Game::create();
        Game::mode = Game::InteractionMode.PLAYING;   //error on this line
    }
    return _GameSingleton;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but you shouldn't use reserved names like `__GAME_SCENE_H__` or `_GameSingleton`.

Comment: yes, thats right. I am just using them to post here on SO. Not in my actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
Game::mode = Game::InteractionMode.PLAYING
```

write directly

```
Game::mode = PLAYING
```

Also, as `mode` is `static`, you must define it outside the class, adding:

```
Game::InteractionMode Game::mode;
```

Answer (score 3):

Enumeration-constants are in the scope of the surrounding object, so you can do e.g.:

```
Game::mode = Game::PLAYING;
```

Or, since the function is in the scope of the `Game` class already:

```
mode = PLAYING;
```

Or, if you really want to use full scoping, you use the scope-operator `::` for the enumeration as well:

```
Game::mode = Game::InteractionMode::PLAYING;
```

Comment: Note that full scoping isn't standard compliant when using pre-C++11. MSVC supports it though.

Comment: `Game::InteractionMode::PLAYING` is only possible if it's a scoped enumeration (`enum class`). Unscoped enumeration values such as those in the question are always in the surrounding scope.

Comment: Also, within a member function, `mode = PLAYING` is enough unless you enjoy decorating your code with unnecessary noise.

Answer (score 0):

The items of an enumeration are defined within the enclosing type, in your case `class Game`. The name of the enum does not become part of the item. Your error can be fixed by using `Game::PLAYING`.

In C++11 it is possible to include the enum's name as well, so you could say `Game::InteractionMode::PLAYING`. With MSVC this works with earlier C++ versions, too, but you get a warning about a non-standard extension. In any case you must use `::` instead of `.`.

If you use a C++11 compliant compiler, you could do the following:

```
enum class InteractionMode {
        EDITING,
        PLAYING };
// [...]
mode = Game::InteractionMode::PLAYING;
```

Including `class` allows the full scoping.